# SQL query to delete rows when one column is empty and a combination of another three exists without an empty string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have something like this:

```
id_flow    id_question    order               questionText
   1            2           1        How do I remove the row below?"
   1            2           1          
   1            1           2
```

we wouldn't want to remove the third row because no other combination (1,1,2) exists... but we would want to remove the second.

It is only to delete where `questionText` is an empty string AND the three columns have a duplicate that has a value for `questionText` that is not empty.

I am probably missing basic SQL concept here, but can someone help?

Comment: what if you have 3 different rows with the same key and only 1 is blank?

Comment: @DanielE. the only time the row wouldn't be deleted is when `questionText` is blank and when there also exists a row that has a combination of `id_flow`, `id_question`, and `[order]` that matches AND has a non-empty string stored in `questionText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have a server to try out the syntax right now, but logically this should do

```sql
WITH cte2
AS (
    SELECT id_flow
        ,id_question
        ,ORDER
    FROM tab
    WHERE LEN(questiontext) = 0

    INTERSECT

    SELECT id_flow
        ,id_question
        ,ORDER
    FROM tab
    WHERE LEN(questionText) > 0
    )
DELETE tab
FROM tab
JOIN cte2 ON tab.id_flow = cte2.id_flow
    AND tab.id_question = cte2.id_question
    AND tab.ORDER = cte2.ORDER
    AND LEN(tab.questionText) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete from QTable q
join (
Select COUNT(*) as NoOfRows, id_flow, id_question, id_order
FROM QTable
GROUP BY id_flow, id_question, id_order) q2 
ON q.id_flow=q2.id_flow AND q.id_question = q2.id_question and q.id_order = q2.id_order
WHERE q2.NoOfRows > 1 and q.questionText IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

This will delete all duplicate rows where the three columns are duplicated over two rows or more:

```
with c1 as (
   select id_flow, id_question, [order], 
   row_number() over (partition by id_flow,id_question,[order] 
   order by  d_flow,id_question,[order] ) as counts 
   from t
   )
   delete from c1 where counts > 1 and id_question is not null
```

Comment: It is only to delete where `questionText` is an empty string AND the three columns have a duplicate that has a value for `questionText` that is not empty.